# Set a cell contents depending on multiple conditions in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet where I want the conditions like:

- If all the cells from Range (B1:B30) are blank, put the status as `Not run`
- If any of the cell from Range (B1:B30) is having word Failed then put the final status as `Failed`
- If all the cells from Range (B1:B30) is having word `Pass` then put the final status as `Pass`

Comment: In my excel range there are only three things allowed Pass, Failed or blank. and I have final status appearing in another cell C3. For now I have tried the formula as = IF(COUNTIF(G8:G13|"Not OK")>0|"FAILED"|"PASS")... But there is one problem in this formula if the entire range is blank then also it is showing the status as pass

Comment: yes, if all the cells has word pass then put the final status is pass. However if any of the cell is having word Failed then put the final status as Failed (No matter other cells are having any value)... Third condition is if all the cells are blank then it means the test case never run and in those cases it should put Not run

Comment: The problem is there are three conditions thats why it is creating the problem

Comment: Yes, exactly there are three conditions

Answer (score 1):

Trust this helps:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B1:B30)>0, IF(COUNTIFS(B1:B30, "FAIL")>0, "FAIL", "PASS"), "NOT RUN")
```

[image: Formula Solution]

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures, but by copy-pasting it instead. Images cannot be searched and their contents cannot be copy-pasted.

Comment: Sure :) Will post code too